# Java - Content of List is lost in recursion

Tags: java, list, recursion

I'm currently programming on a little project (which is way to specific to explain here) and I got everything working except one part. I've got a List `pZiegel` by parameter which is modified in recursion. Because it didn't work, I did a little debugging and found the problem: At one point, the list contains exactly one number at the end of the method. Then, the program jumps one recursion depth back. And directly after that, it doesn't contains any numbers anymore. How did it lose the number? Lists as parameters work with pass-by-reference, so it shouldn't just reject it, right?

```
public void erstelleBaum (Tree pTree, List<Integer> pZiegel, List<Integer> pFugen, int tiefe) { 
    if (tiefe / n >= maxHoehe) {
        System.out.println("hi");
        mauerGefunden = true;
        alleFugen = pFugen;
    }
    if (!mauerGefunden) {

        pZiegel.toFirst();
        while (pZiegel.hasAccess() && !mauerGefunden) {
            boolean ziegelHinzufügen = false;
            möglich = true;
            aktZiegel = pZiegel.getContent();

            // ...

            if (möglich) {

                // ...

                pZiegel.remove();

                if (pZiegel.isEmpty()) { 
                    ziegelHinzufügen = true;
                    pZiegel = new List();
                    for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
                        pZiegel.append(i);
                    }
                }


                // Recursion
                erstelleBaum(neuesBlatt, pZiegel, neueFugen, neueTiefe);

                // Here, it tells me that pZiegel is empty (at recursion depth 17)

                if (ziegelHinzufügen) {
                    pZiegel.toFirst();
                    while (pZiegel.hasAccess()) {
                        pZiegel.remove();
                    }
                    pZiegel.append(aktZiegel);
                }
                else {

                    pZiegel.toFirst();
                    while (pZiegel.hasAccess() && pZiegel.getContent() < aktZiegel) {
                        pZiegel.next();
                    }
                    if (pZiegel.hasAccess()) {
                        pZiegel.insert(aktZiegel);
                        pZiegel.toFirst();
                        while (pZiegel.getContent() != aktZiegel) {
                            pZiegel.next();
                        }
                    }
                    else {               
                        pZiegel.toLast();
                        pZiegel.append(aktZiegel);
                        pZiegel.toLast();
                    }
                }
            }              
            pZiegel.next();
        }
    }
    // Here, pZiegel contained one number (at recursion depth 18)
}
```

I hope, the code isn't too messy. I tried to keep out the parts that doesn't involve pZiegel. And sorry, that the variables are named in german. I didn't want to change them for this post because I know I would forget to change something in the code.

Feel free to ask, if something is unclear.

Comment: Have you tried debugging it? If not may be this is the best time to learn one of the best perks of programming, i.e. how to debug.

Comment: Like I said, I tried debugging. I used the console to get an overview of what's happening. And I really can't explain how that number got lost.

Comment: `append` isn't a method on `java.util.List`, which is what many would assume you mean by `List`. Which list class are you using?

Comment: "Lists as parameters work with pass-by-reference" no, they are pass by value, like everything in Java. But the "value" here is the value of the variable, not the thing it points to. It's like passing a pointer in C++.

Comment: You're right. I should mention that I'm using a really simple custom class that I got from school. The append method is just adding the content at the end of the list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the *pZiegel* List reference is being lost at some point. You should check the *pZiegel* object ID (a number displayed when you inspect the object) to make sure it is the same List instance all over the recursions.

Notice that there's one part of your code that makes the *pZiegel* identifier **reference a new List**:

```
...
            if (pZiegel.isEmpty()) { 
                ziegelHinzufügen = true;
                pZiegel = new List();  // <---- this line
                for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
                    pZiegel.append(i);
                }
            }
...
```

I believe you are calling the 18th recursion with *pZiegel* referencing one list (maybe empty). Inside the 18th recursion that line is called and *pZiegel* starts referencing a new List (realize that the last List still exists and is referenceed by the *pZiegiel* identifier of the 17th recursion). On the last line of the 18th recursion call you believe you are inspecting the same *pZiegiel* List from the 17th recursion, but that's not the case.

Comment: Thanks! By deleting that line (which was useless anyway...) the problem didn't happen anymore. :)